# Преобразование массива в словарь выдаёт ошибку: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, словари, type-error

Я стал использовать функцию в этом тестовом коде:

```
f = open("keys.txt", "r")
Inkeys = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in range(0, len(Inkeys)):
    Inkeys[i] = Inkeys[i].replace('\n', '')
    Inkeys[i] = Inkeys[i].replace('\r', '')
print(Inkeys)
keys = ***dict([x[0].strip().split('=') for x in Inkeys])***
print(keys)
```

В файле keys.txt:

```
474772B4=+78005553535
0A757481=+79005353535
```

При запуске кода выводит первый массив, а в словарь превратить не может:

```
['474772B4=+78005553535', '0A757481=+79005353535']
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\ya\Desktop\data.py", line 8, in <module>
    keys = dict([x[0].strip().split('=') for x in Inkeys])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что вы делаете, но, возможно, `[0]`, т.е. взятие элемента по индексу 0, у вас лишнее. Без него получается словарь:

```
keys = dict([x.strip().split('=') for x in Inkeys])
print(keys)
```

Вывод:

```
{'474772B4': '+78005553535', '0A757481': '+79005353535'}
```